# Concatenating numbers as string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

```
myCoolObject {
  a: 0
  b: 12
  c: 24
}
```

I want to concatenate `a`, `b` and `c` so that they look like a unique string "a-b-c" (or "0-12-24" in the example).

`a`, `b` and `c` will always represent numbers. Converting each one of them from int to string require a lot of code: I'd just use `sprintf()` if I were in PHP or C, but how can I do this in JS without using `toString()` for each parameter and writing too much code?

Whole code:

```
var pickedDate = this.getSelectedDay().year.toString() + "-" + this.getSelectedDay().month.toString() + this.getSelectedDay().day.toString();
```

Seriously? Isn't there any more efficient way of doing this in js?

Comment: Will the properties always be a, b and c or is there an arbitrary number of properties in each object?

Comment: nope, same data structure all the times.

Comment: Yea, I think what you have is probably the best way.  You can perhaps create a `toString` prototype on whatever object holds this data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myCoolString = myCoolObject.a + '-' + myCoolObject.b + '-' + myCoolObject.c;
```

EDIT:

With ES6, you can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to interpolate numbers into strings:

```
let myCoolString = `${myCoolObject.a}-${myCoolObject.b}-${myCoolObject.c}`;
```

### Try it:

```js
var myCoolObject = {
  a: 0,
  b: 12,
  c: 24
};

var myCoolString = myCoolObject.a + '-' + myCoolObject.b + '-' + myCoolObject.c;

console.log(typeof myCoolString);
console.log(myCoolString);
```

Comment: they're numbers: wouldn't js try to sum them?

Comment: @Saturnix Because there's a string being concatenated in between. If you just wanted to concatenate them (without characters in between), you could just use `var str = "" + myCoolObject.a + myCoolObject.b + myCoolObject.c;`. As soon as a string is encountered, concatenation will happen, not addition. If addition is needed, parentheses can be used

Comment: I added a jsFiddle example to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I do this in JS without [...] writing too much code?

If you know all of your numbers are positive, you can write even less code to achieve the same as we know *JavaScript* executes left-to-right.

```
var obj = {a: 0, b: 12, c: 24}; /* define object
String + Number = String
                  String + Number = String
                                    String + Number = String
String + Number + Number + Number     = String    */
  ''   +  obj.a + -obj.b + -obj.c; // = "0-12-24"
```

The `-` were inserted because `String + -Number = "String-Number"`, e.g.

```
'AK' + -47 // "AK-47"
```

Comment: +1 I don't know why this has been downvoted - looks like a legit answer to me.

Comment: legit okay but how is anyone supposed to maintain this code? You save two quotation marks and one plus sign compared to rink's answer and in exchange readability takes a huge hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly done with `Array.join`:

```
var pickedDate = [
    this.getSelectedDay().year, 
    this.getSelectedDay().month, 
    this.getSelectedDay().day
].join("-")
```

Although I personally prefer a small utility function similar to pythonic `format()`:

```
format = function(fmt /*, args */) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return fmt.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function($0, $1) { 
        return String(args[$1])
    })
}
```

and then:

```
var pickedDate = format('{0}-{1}-{2}', 
    this.getSelectedDay().year, 
    this.getSelectedDay().month, 
    this.getSelectedDay().day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without much code it looks perfect here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpgyr/7/)

```
myObj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 12,
  c: 24
}; 

var r="";

// iterate through all object properties
for (var p in myObj) 
{
    //concatenate it
    r+=myObj[p]+"-";
}

//remove the last dash
r=r.substring(0,r.length-1);

alert(r.substring(0,r.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **Try [sprintf()](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) for JavaScript.**
2. **Add new method to string**

   ```
   if (!String.prototype.format) {
   String.prototype.format = function() {
      var args = arguments;
      return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
         return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
          ? args[number]
           : match
         ;
      });
     };
   }

   "{0} - {1} - {2}".format(myCoolObject.a, myCoolObject.b,myCoolObject.c)
   ```

Comment: Please link to the [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/989121) instead of copypasting it.